# Query Multi_Field with Elasticutils

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticutils

I have defined in Elastic Search the following mapping for my index with one multi_field type.

```
{
    'station': {
       "properties" :{
           'id': {'type': 'integer'},
           'call': {'type': 'multi_field', 
                    'fields' : {
                               'call': {'type': 'string', 'analyzer': 'whitespace'},
                               'raw': {'type': 'string', 'index': 'not_analyzed'}
                               }
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

I like Mozilla's ElasticUltis, but I couldn't find a way to query the multi_field fields.

I would have expected something like:

```
myQuery = S.query(call_raw__wildcard="value")
```

Does anyone know how to Query a multi_field field with elasticutils?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I found a work around in the  [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-multi-field-type.html) docs (tnx @DrTech). If "path":"just_name" is added, the field (in the question "call.raw") can be accessed without the "call" prefix. Then the mapping would look like this:

```
{
'station': {
   "properties" :{
       'id': {'type': 'integer'},
       'call': {'type': 'multi_field', 
                'path' : 'just_name',
                'fields' : {
                           'call': {'type': 'string', 'analyzer': 'whitespace'},
                           'raw': {'type': 'string', 'index': 'not_analyzed'}
                           }
                }
    }
}
```

}

Unfortunately, it's just a workaround. Maybe someone else has a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

First, your `multi_field` definition is incorrect. You should have a `call` main field at the same level as `raw` and `autocomplete`.  See the [`multi_field` docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-multi-field-type.html).

Then you can query the main field as `call`, and the raw field as `call.raw`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake in my multi_field definition. I have updated the definition accordingly. Unfortunately, ElasticUtils does not allow `myQuery=S.query(call.raw__wildcard="value")`. So I'm still wondering if there is a way with ElasticUtils to access the "call.raw" field

Comment: No idea about ElasticUtils - I'd look at using the official Python client http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/index.html - it exposes the full Elasticsearch API so you don't have to work around the client implementation.